# issues with replacing a div with a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created an html page, (template if you will) so what I would like to do is to leave the page all on it's own and use AJAX / jQuery to propagate the div elements with other external html pages.

Is this possible ?

I have been checking around and I have yet to find the solution.

Here is a snippet of my nav list...

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li id="n-c"><span class="dir">Cosmo</span>
        <ul id="switcheroo">
            <li class="first"><a href="pg1.html">Special</a></li>
            <li><a href="pg2.html">Mineral</a></li>
            <li><a href="pg3.html">Lateral</a></li>
            <li><a href="pg4.html">Tangent</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my content section I have added a

```
<div id="contentSwap"></div>
```

I tried this:

```
$("ul #switcheroo li a").click(function(event) {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(href, function(data) {
    $('#contentSwap').html(data);
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

to no avail, can someone help me?

**WDH**

---

---

in the end I ended up using the simplest form to achieve my result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#switcheroo").click(function(event){
           $('#contentSwap2').load('pg2.html');
       }); 
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#switcheroo2").click(function(event){
           $('#contentSwap3').load('pg3.html');
       }); 
    });

</script>


                   ... and so on ...
```

---

And ultimately swapping the div id with the one that had content already, instead of using an empty tag.

**WDH**

I appreciate all your insight @abdullah.abcoder @ShankarSangoli and @John Hartsock

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is HTML, then you can do the following using jQuery [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('#contentSwap').replaceWith(data);
```

Also, you may want to only import the portion of the HTML from the data by doing the following:

```
$('#contentSwap').replaceWith($('#somedivElement', data));
```

Comment: Same result as the comment above.

Comment: @WebDevHed... I was not actually providing a direct solution but an idea on how to approach your problem.  As I have no idea of your end results, it is difficult for me to help you. Perhaps you could mock up a sample scenario on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul #switcheroo li a").click(function(event) {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#contentSwap').load('' + href + ''); //$('#contentSwap').empty().load(''+ href +''); you may use this for make your `#contantSwap` empty and then append contents to it
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

***I hope this will works***

Comment: Alright so I tried this and what it does is open up the linked html page in the same window. Bypassing the original goal of having only the div switch.

Comment: @WebDevHed check out this solution

Answer (score 0):

When you get the html response in the get callback it will have all the tags starting from html, head body etc. Either you will have to make sure you only send the required markup from the server or parse the markup and and get only the markup that you want to append into **contentSwap** div.

The other approach is to use iframe, set the iframe source to href, onload of iframe find the required element, get the markup and then append it to **contentSwap** div.

```
$("ul #switcheroo li a").click(function(event) {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var dIf = $("#dummyIframe");

if(dIf.length == 0){
    $(document.body).append('<iframe id="dummyIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
     dIf = $("#dummyIframe").onload(function(){
        var iFrameContent = $("#dummyIframe").contents();
        $('#contentSwap', window.parent.document)
        .html(iFrameContent.find('#someDivIdOrAnyOtherSelector').html());
      });
 }
 dIf[0].src = href;

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
```